# For loop variable initialisation from a list

Tags: groovy

Groovy allows unfolding lists in assignment, as in:

```
(x, y) = [1, 2]
```

So I assumed something similar would work in a for loop, as in:

```
list = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]]
for ((elm1, elm2) in list) {...}
```

Which turns out to be a syntax error. Is this style not possible or is there some trick to it I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it won't work with the `for` loop (or I definitely don't know the syntax), however a two-argument closure can be used to iterate such a `List`, unfold the tuples:

```
def list = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]]
assert list.collect { a, b -> a + b } == [3, 6, 9, ]
```